# Angular 2 - Component variable from service is not changed in the view

Tags: angular

I have `MainMenuComponent` with some navigation links.
Some links are for signed members, some for guests, and some for everyone.

My master template (`master.html`) looks like this:

```
<main-menu></main-menu>

<div class="container">
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

inside my `router-outlet`, I have a `login component`. When I login, I change my `JwtService.jwtToken` variable to the user token. (a service variable)

That means that after login, I can still see the "Login" and "Register" menu links:

```
<li *ngIf="!JwtService.getToken()" [class.active]="isRouteActive(['/Login'])"><a [routerLink]="['Login']">Login</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="!JwtService.getToken()" [class.active]="isRouteActive(['/Register'])"><a [routerLink]="['Register']">Register</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="JwtService.getToken()" [class.active]="isRouteActive(['/Fight'])"><a [routerLink]="['Fight']">Fight</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="JwtService.getToken()"><a (click)="logOut()">Log Out</a></li>
```

Why does JwtService.getToken() is changed in my `<router-outlet>` but outside it, in my main menu component, its not updating? (unless I refresh the page manually)

**In other words: When my service variable is changed after login using `jwtService.setToken("MY_TOKEN");`
,The following expression in my view is not changed:

```
JwtService.getToken()
```

and it remains null until I refresh my browser/route **

Comment: That's not a lot of information what's going on in your application. Can you create a plunker?

Comment: My application is really big and there are many unrelevant parts of code to my issue. Please let me know what information is needed to resolve this issue or get general knowledge about it. I updated my post for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with components outside the `router-outlet` in Angular2 caused by zones and change detection strategy.

You can force Angular2 to check the full component tree by using the `ApplicationRef.tick()` method.

In your `login` component:

Add the reference to `ApplicationRef`

```
import {ApplicationRef} from 'angular2/core';
```

inject the `ApplicationRef` into the constructor:

```
constructor(public appRef: ApplicationRef)
```

then when you receive the response from the authentication service force the Angular2 app to go through the change detection again:

```
this.appRef.tick(); // this will refresh the bindings
```

Your `main-menu` component should get updated as expected.

Comment: Could you  paste the code for: main-menu component, JwtService and the main bootstrap component?